# Industry Standard for Single user web app

Tags: html, css, node.js, web-applications

I am new to web development so this question might be basic. I was asked to create a photography site in node.js for a friend. I want to create a way for only her to login to the site and fill out forms and update content. Should I put the login link on the main page like other web apps or create a secret route that she can go to and login?

sorry for the newbie question.

I have googled extensively on this subject and even took an online web-developer course. I cant seem to find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Google Firebase has some pretty good authentication stuff for applying access controls. It really depends what kind of security you need.

Consider this. Some other user gets a hold of the route that you've provided. Your client's site could be completely sabotaged.

My suggestions is to check out Google Firebase Authentication it will be worth while to know that suite if you are doing independent contracting work.